# Is it possible to do a elastic dump with a lambda task in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I need to do a elastic dump every week. I think that i could create a lambda function do that job but I don't know how to setup [elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) there. is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your options are the below:

1. Use the [snapshot api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html). Read carefully the documentation so you know exactly what you are saving. It's not only data. After that you can use the [restore api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html). Again read carefully the docs, because there is downtime involved.
2. Use a node module like `elasticdump` as you already have. You can find in [AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) what are your options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Where can i save the data on the lambda environment? I can use elasticdump but I need some storage in the lambda environment to copy to any place. Do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: You should use S3 for that. You can't save them and then get them elsewhere. You have to stream the data